# How can script be executed in Selenium JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a test.html page, here's code for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="test" onMouseover="alert('1')">this is new one</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to use Selenium JavascriptExecutor to simulate mouse over event on span in test page, so I wrote code like this:

```
@Test
public void testJSExecutor(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    webDriver.get("file:\\\\C:/test.html");

    String script = "function test(){var t=document.getElementById('test');"
            + "if( document.createEvent ) {"
            + "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"
            + "evObj.initEvent( 'mouseover', true, false );"
            + "elem.dispatchEvent(evObj);"
            +"} else if( document.createEventObject ) {"
            + "elem.fireEvent('onmouseover');"
            +"}} window.onload=test;";
    jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
    jsExecutor.executeScript(script);
}
```

But after run this code, no alert prompted.

How could mouse over event be valid so alert could be prompted?

Comment: Have you tried using Actions class to do mouseover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate the mouse hover action using the below code..

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("test"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.perform();
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. :) And sorry for can not vote your answer up, because of less reputation. :(

Comment: Accepted this answer, thanks again for your help. :)